# PrimeNG tree doesn't display properly when I add selectionMode attribute

Tags: angular, tree, primeng

Here is my basic tree : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMVze.jpg

And here is what happends when I try to add `selectionMode="checkbox"`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPnAn.jpg to my `<p-tree value="files></p-tree>`

Do you have any suggestions of what it could come from ?

Comment: Can you add your code instead of just the picture?

Comment: In HTML template : `<p-tree [value]="files" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedFiles"></p-tree>`

Comment: In .ts : `selectedFiles: TreeNode[];` and the "files" is a copy/paste of the doc example

Comment: I'm not sure but did you try to import CheckboxModule?

Comment: @Yaël what is the version of Angular and primeng?

Comment: Importing CheckboxModule doesn't solve the problem. My Angular version is 4.2.5.

Comment: And primeng version is 4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution :

Import these two .css files from primeng into the global.css of my project.

`@import '../../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css';`
`@import '../../../../../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';`